# webrtc no second client helo dtls

Tags: firefox, video, stream, webrtc, dtls

We have writen a small server side application which can send video stream to the borwser. It worked well on Firefox before the 36.0.3 version.
Since then the client does not allways send the second client hello of DTLS.
Is there a reason for this? 
And what should I do in such case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From FF 37.0 there are no two separate ports for video and audio.

PS
FF 37.0.1 made further changes in ICE negotiation.